# SharePoint Search - Result Source to retrieve only 5 People along with rest of the results

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, people-search, kql-query, fql

Can you please help me in formulating a KQL or FQL query?

Is it possible to retrieve only 5 people results from the below query. Rest 15 can be anything from the index of the SharePoint Search Service.

{?{searchTerms} ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople **TOP 5**}

Top 5 refers only People results

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `RowLimit=5` to the query string (not the query), that works for a REST query. If you are working in a web part you can usually specify the number of results in the Web Part properties. Same applies to Query Rules.

Comment: Thank you for the response Matthew. 

I am looking to limit only people results to 5 in the Search using KQL that we get from the "Launch Query Builder" from the Search Result Sources under "Site Collection Administration" in the SP Settings page.

{?{searchTerms} ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople RowLimit/Top=5}  --> This will not work. Do we have any other alternative?